# What is a quick way to set up an http server in a java unit test and make assertions against it?

Tags: java, http, junit, simple-framework

My unit test calls components that make http interactions. I want to set up an http server before I run the test, and then make assertions after the test to see if the expected interactions occurred.

Mocking is too low level for several reasons, including that i want to exercise network interactions as part of the test.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Simple Framework](http://simpleframework.org), which you can include via gradle like this:

`testCompile 'org.simpleframework:simple:5.+'`

You can write a test case like this:

```
public class HttpMockingTest {

    class TestContainer implements Container {

        int n = 0;

        @Override
        public void handle(Request req, Response resp) {

             // count
             n += 1;

            // close the response
            try {
                resp.getOutputStream().close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test0() throws IOException {

        // this sets up the server
        TestContainer testContainer = new TestContainer();
        Server server = new ContainerServer(testContainer);
        SocketConnection socketConnection = new SocketConnection(server);
        InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9999);
        socketConnection.connect(inetSocketAddress);

        // this invokes the server
        int n = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {
                CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("http://localhost:9999/foo"));
            }
        }

        // make assertions
        assertEquals(n, testContainer.n);
    }
}
```